# How can I connect to Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet

I have just installed **Ubuntu 18.04.3** for studying purposes. I cannot connect to internet in any way as the **WI-FI adapter is not found** and every other solution to the problem I have looked up on the internet requires a **wired connection** to the internet, which will not work for me as **my notepad does not have a Ethernet port**, it can only use wireless connections and Bluetooth. My notepad is Asus Vivobook S14 S431F. Please help me!

Comment: So if you run `lsusb` and `lspci`, there is no wifi adapter listed at all?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, on the same model of the VivoBook S14.
The output of lspci -knn|grep Net:

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9df0] (rev30)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi

output of rfkill list:
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Answer (score -1):

As noted at https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-S14-S431FA/Tech-Specs/

[image: picture of ports]

you have a USB3 Gen 2 port. Attach a micro USB3 to Ehternet adapter there and you will have wired Ethernet capability, with which you can use solutions which require a connection to download a file.

Comment: How does it solve the Wi-Fi problem?

Comment: "I cannot connect to internet in any way as the WI-FI adapter is not found and every other solution to the problem I have looked up on the internet requires a wired connection to the internet" Solution provided.

Comment: This is not a solution of the wireless problem at all. Besides OP doesn't need to buy a USB Ethernet adapter to fix the wireless problem. OP can use an offline method, or use a phone USB tethering. So the answer isn't useful.